# Unable to convert string to date (dd/MMM,YYYY) format ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
   var LR_No_Of_Days = "";

     $("#DateRange").jqxDateTimeInput({ width: 250, height: 25, selectionMode: 'range' }); $("#DateRange").on('change', function (event) {
            var selection = $("#DateRange").jqxDateTimeInput('getRange');

            if (selection.from != null) {
                $("#selection").html("<div>From: " + selection.from.toLocaleDateString() + " <br/>To: " + selection.to.toLocaleDateString() + "</div>");

            }
           var LR_Request_Date_From = selection.from.toLocaleDateString();
           var LR_Request_Date_To = selection.to.toLocaleDateString();
           $('#LR_Request_Date_From').val(LR_Request_Date_From);
           $('#LR_Request_Date_To').val(LR_Request_Date_To);
           NoOfdays();
           function NoOfdays() {
               var LR_No_Of_Days = Math.floor((Date.parse(LR_Request_Date_To) - Date.parse(LR_Request_Date_From)) / 86400000); if (LR_No_Of_Days == '0') {LR_No_Of_Days = 1;} else { LR_No_Of_Days-1; }; alert(LR_Request_Date_From + "  &&& " + LR_Request_Date_To + "  No of days:" + LR_No_Of_Days);
    $("#LR_No_Of_Days").val(LR_No_Of_Days);}});
```

I'm unable to convert the string variable(LR_Request_Date_From and LR_Request_Date_To) to date format. I receive error converting string to date.

Comment: this is a javascript question, not a .NET question. Am I correct? If you want to parse dates in unusual formats such as this, I highly recommend MomentJs (www.momentjs.com). Specifically this function: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ . Doing this yourself in JS is a bit of a headache, and the momentJS people have figured it all out for you, already

Comment: I'm doing a .Net program form HR leave request form, this is a .Net Question.

Comment: ok...but there's no .NET code in the example. It's all JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use MM instead of mm and CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as second parameter

```
string dt = DateTime.Parse(txtVADate.Text.Trim()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```